# What is the meaning of "Is she thinking what I think she is thinking?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "Is she thinking what I think she is thinking? " ? (Source: PHONICS PC COMICS Volume 5 ISSUE 1)

Dose it mean "Is she thinking a thing that I think. I think a thing that she is thinking" ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's meant to be disbelief at what the serving lady is thinking.**

The context of the comic is, from what I see, that the trio of girls has somehow had a spell put on them that allows them to read minds - to see what people are thinking. We can see them seeing this - for instance, the girl who is *thinking* - not saying - "I am so much prettier than Ivy".

In the middle panel, the serving lady is *saying* that there's soup. But she's *thinking* "With lots of giraffe spit for flavor!". This is, naturally, disgusting, so pink-haired girl - one of the ones who can read minds - is shocked, and exclaims in disbelief "Is she thinking what I think she is thinking?"

So the "is she thinking" part is a question, meant rhetorically - asking the other girls who can read minds if the serving lady is indeed actually thinking "what I think she's thinking" - in other words, what the pink-haired girl is seeing that the serving lady is thinking.

To rephrase the sentence, we could put it like this:

> Can I believe what I just saw that the serving lady is thinking (that there's giraffe spit in the soup)?

It's supposed to be an exclamation of disbelief and disgust at what the serving lady is thinking about what's in their food.